# Timer se ejecuta varias veces en un segundo en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy terminando un trabajo con un cliente y me ocurrió un problema con el timer de mi aplicación en flutter, lo que pasa es que estoy ejecutando un timer cada segundo cuando se ejecuta también ejecuta otras cosas pero el error es que este se ejecuta varias veces por segundo.

```
Widget _screen(BuildContext context, deviceData, int prevNum) {
    now = new DateTime.now();
    dynamic currentTime = DateFormat.jms().format(now);

    // Cada segundo actualiza el reloj
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        now = new DateTime.now();
        currentTime = DateFormat.jms().format(now);
        minutes = int.parse(DateFormat('mm').format(now));
        int sec = int.parse(DateFormat('ss').format(now));
        print(sec);
      });
      ...
```

Comment: si _screen lo llamas dentro del metodo build, entonces estas creando varios timers

Answer (score 0):

diegoveloper tiene razón, además encontré una pregunta similar en donde pueden ver que se puede hacer en este caso por si alguien tiene la misma pregunta.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569602/flutter-run-function-every-x-amount-of-seconds